# query from different oracle connections in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 connections with different tables in sqldeveloper.

let's say:

ConnectionA with tables: A,B,C
ConnectionB with tables: D,E,F

Now I want to have a query that looks like this:

select aa.name,dd.id
from A aa,D dd;

How can i do this?

Comment: Tables are not connection specific. Perhaps you mean schemas?

Comment: In sqldeveloper you can create connections which have their own tables

Comment: @user999379 - Connections do not have tables.  Connections allow you to log in to a particular database as a particular user that owns a particular set of objects (a schema).  The connection does not own any objects.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to query objects in two different databases using a single SQL statement, you would need to create a database link between the two databases.  A database link is an object that resides in the database and is independent of the query tool.  In database A, for example, you could create the database link

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK to_b
  CONNECT TO username IDENTIFIED BY password
  USING tns_alias_on_a_pointing_to_b
```

And then when you connect to A, you could do something like

```
SELECT aa.name, dd.id
  FROM a aa,
       d@to_b dd
 WHERE aa.some_key = dd.some_key
```

Comment: i get this error: SQL Error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Comment: @user999379 - You get this error, I assume, when you run the `SELECT` statement?  When you create the database link, the TNS alias needs to exist on database A and needs to point to database B.  The TNS alias on A pointing to B may be different than the TNS alias defined in your local system (particularly if you're using local naming with a local tnsnames.ora file).

Comment: We have a "live" database and a "demo" database running on the same Oracle DB server.  They are both set up in the same tnsnames.ora file.  So for me it was as simple as executing this statement under my live connection: `CREATE DATABASE LINK demodb USING 'demodb';` where demodb is the SID of our demo database in tnsnames.ora.  Now I can query demo database tables from my live db connection by just appending @demodb on the end of the table name.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently [TOAD Data Point](https://www.quest.com/toad/) supports *Cross-Connection Queries* , see:

http://dev.toadfordataanalyst.com/webhelp/Content/Query_Builder/Create_CrossConnection_Queries.htm

Also [Oracle SQL Developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_SQL_Developer) seems to support something similar. (see this blog post: [Cross Connection Queries](http://barrymcgillin.blogspot.si/2010/11/cross-connection-queries.html))

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful and to the point of the OP question for Oracle 11g rel 2 and later: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_how_create_database_link.htm .  Basically, right-click on the connection in the Connections pane in SQL Developer, click Properties, and you get the hostname, port, and service name that you can plug into the "USING" part of the CREATE DATABASE LINK statement.  Whether you put in Service Name or SID I assume depends on which you used in your connection. example:

`create public database link
  mylink
connect to
  remote_username
identified by
  mypassword
using 'myserver:1521/MYSID';`

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't have SID and have Service Name instead - what would be the syntax after the USING keyword?